# How to plot multiple seaborn catplots on a 2x2 grid?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I tried to use the FacetGrid to plot a 2x2-grid with each subplot being a catplot of the same data, but just with different 'jitter' values. It didn't worked.

Here is the code I am using now:

```
sns.catplot(x="Sex", y="SidestepDist", jitter=False, data=daten_csv)
sns.catplot(x="Sex", y="SidestepDist", jitter=0.2, data=daten_csv)
sns.catplot(x="Sex", y="SidestepDist", jitter=0.5, data=daten_csv)
sns.catplot(x="Sex", y="SidestepDist", jitter=1, data=daten_csv)
```

But of course I get the plots below each other like this: 
[image]

How could I have a main plot, with all 4 subplots placed as a 2x2 matrix (grid)?

Comment: It's not too clear what did not work when using a `FacetGrid`. In any case consider producing a normal matplotlib grid via `plt.subplots(2,2)` and plot a seaborn `stripplot` to each subplot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't want to make the question too long. I got white axes when trying FacetGrid. But you could ignore the part of the question with FacetGrid. How could one change the code I posted, to have a 2x2 grid plot, with that subplots above in it?

Comment: yes, exactly! Thx for the follow up

Comment: Can we treat each question aside, as they are two different questions, asked in two different contexts, concerning two different subjects? Besides that, if you read the title of the question, it states clearly enough that I am asking how to do that with "Seaborn catplots". If you could deliver a helpful answer, thank you, if not, commenting each question won't bring us further.. I don't think that I will take the time to write a question, take screenshots, explain it, and post it here, if I knew the answer.

Comment: I could provide an answer explaining why it's impossible to do with `catplot`s. Supposedly that won't bring you further towards your goal. That's why instead I suggested to use  a subplot grid and plot seaborn `stripplot`s to it. That should be pretty straight forward, but if it isn't one would need to see where you're stuck.

Comment: If you could deliver a helpful answer, thank you, if not, grab some pop-corn and wait for an answer with me! I don't think that I will take the time to write a question, take screenshots, explain it, and post it here, if I knew the answer. And I don't think I can answer it myself, because if I did, I would be so dope, my life would be so dope, and I won't chill so long here asking question left and right :)

Comment: I'm sorry for having bothered you by trying to help. If you follow my advice from above, creating a `plt.subplots(2,2)` grid and plot a `stripplot` to each subplot, you will get your desired plot. If you're stuck with that, I can help further if provided any clue on the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't know how to use matplotlib subplots, with seaborn and stripplot. If you could provide a code snippet, I would be really grateful for that.

Comment: Anyone could help here please?

Answer (score 4):

So.. I figure it out, with the great help of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Here is the way to do it:

## Plot the Sidestep distance against Sex

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(12,10))
jitter = [[False, 1], [0.5, 0.2]]

for j in range(len(ax)):
    for i in range(len(ax[j])):
        ax[j][i].tick_params(labelsize=15)
        ax[j][i].set_xlabel('label', fontsize=17, position=(.5,20))
        ax[j][i].set_ylabel('label', fontsize=17)
        # x as Hindernisabstand hinzufügen 
        ax[j][i] = sns.stripplot(x="Sex", y="SidestepDist", jitter=jitter[j][i], data=daten_csv, ax=ax[j][i])
fig.suptitle('Categorical Features Overview', position=(.5,1.1), fontsize=20)
fig.tight_layout()

fig.show()
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image: plot overview]